# Does zero padding in Keras requires a memory?

Tags: keras, zero-padding

Does zero padding in Keras require a memory?

```
 model.add(ZeroPadding2D((1, 1)))
```

if it yes does, is it will be like this?

```
INPUT: [224x224x3]          Memory: 224*224*3=150K      Weight: 0
ZEROPAD_1: [226x226x3]      Memory: 226*226*3=153K      Weight: 0
CONV2D_1-64: [224x224x64]   Memory: 224*224*64=3.2M     Weight: ((3*3*3)*64)+64= 1,792
```